# How to add an api to Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, api, ide, visual-studio-code

I am new at using Visual Studio Code and I am looking to add an api library that I have to VS code so that the Javascript IDE can provide intellisense code completion.

In the past I used Eclipse IDE and added the file to my libs folder in my workspace. This doesn't seem to be the case for VS Code.

The file is a just a .js file that contains a javascript "skeleton" for the API that is intended to be used in a Javascript IDE.

Here is a link to the file.https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ywltqbi7ar0pfa/concept_api.js?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comment to the top of your file pointing to the "skeleton":

```
/// <reference path="./api.js">
```

VS Code should even give you code completion in the `path` string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `jsconfig.json` file in the root of your Visual Studio Code project and add all files you want parsing for code completion.

```
{
    "include": [
        "www/js/*.js",
        "www/lib/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Programming with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense)

As of the above page VS Code's intellisense is provided using TypeScript. It is recommended that you create Typings for your library if you are planning to ship the library.

But adding a comment like

///     <reference path="you_file.js">

will give you some help with code completion but the accuracy of the completion is a question.

If you are planning to ship the library

Visit [This page](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) for more help